# Use multiple '?' paremeter in prepared statement

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am getting Some **run-time errors** while trying to use the **insert** statement in C++. I want to use **2** or **more** "**?**" to insert email and **username** to a **player** but I am getting some errors. Any ideas of where the problem is?

```
string userInfo = "INSERT INTO PLAYERTABLE (EmailAddress,UserName)";
        userInfo += " VALUES (?,?)"; 

    PreparedStatement *prepareStatement;
    (*connection)->setAutoCommit(false); //Disable auto commit

    prepareStatement = (*connection)->prepareStatement(TABLEUSERFRIENDS);

    //Make sure User input is correct is NOT MySQL Injection
    prepareStatement->setString(1, "tt@yahoo.com");

    prepareStatement->setString(2, "myusername");

    prepareStatement->executeUpdate();

    (*connection)->commit(); //Save Data
```

The error I am getting is

**Error Occured because of You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 
PLAYERTABLE ' at line 1**

Comment: It seems odd you have to de-reference `connection` before using it like that. Do you have some kind of double-pointer for some reason?

Comment: what is the variable `TABLEUSERFRIENDS` doing here? Did you mean to write there `userInfo`?

Comment: @tadman I have connecction as a Connection **connection

Comment: @Florian Moser, that was the problem. thanks. but now I am getting another error that says "Error Occured because of No database selected"

What does that even mean?

Comment: use (*connection)->setSchema("YourDatabaseName") to select the database

Comment: @Programmer Having a pointer to a pointer seems really odd. Why not just pass a pointer around?

Comment: I know it is but that is the option I have. I have "Connection *con " in the main function. I want to pass it around to other functions and be able to modify it there. For example, my function name to "connecToServer(Connection *connection){}" will be called from the main function with "connecToServer(&con);" That way, I can modify con from main function in other functions. Example of when I need to modify it and be able to re-use it is when I want to connect to database with something like this "*connection = driver->connect("", "", "");" Let me know if there is another way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example from prepare_statement.cpp (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html) :

```
/*The first useful example - prepare() once, execute() n + 1 times 
 NOTE: The MySQL Server does not support named parameters. You have to use 
 the placeholder syntax shown below. There is no emulation which would you 
 allow to use named parameter like ':param1'. Use '?'. Parameters are 1-based. 
 */ 
 num_rows = 0; 
 prep_stmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id, label) VALUES (?, ?)")); 
 for (i = 0; i < EXAMPLE_NUM_TEST_ROWS; i++) { 
    prep_stmt->setInt(1, test_data[i].id); 
    prep_stmt->setString(2, test_data[i].label); 
    /* executeUpdate() returns the number of affected = inserted rows */ 
    num_rows += prep_stmt->executeUpdate(); 
 }
```

So you need to pass the SQL (userInfo) as the parameter to the prepareStatement function.